# Show all tables from database into select form in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hiho,
I have a little problem with showing all table names on page in  form .

Code bellow:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showTables(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a table:</option>';
$result = mysql_list_tables($db_name);
for ($i = 0; $i < count(mysql_num_rows($result)); $i++){
echo '<option value="' . mysql_tablename($result, $i) . '">' . mysql_tablename($result, $i) . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>
</form>
<br> 
<div id="tablesDb"><b>All content from selected table will be listed there.</b></div></div>';
```

I try with mysqli too ,and i get results but still without names of the tables and nothing can be select.

Maybe someone know how to get this work.

Comment: Query the information_schema

Answer (score 0):

First, you definitely want to be using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), as the MySQL extension is deprecated. Second, you can probably get all of the data you need in a simple `SELECT` query like this:

```
select `TABLE_NAME` from information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mydbname = 'database_name';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password",$mydbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$options = '';

 // for the query you can use two of the following lines (line1+line2  OR line3+line4)
//Use line (line1+line2)
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");
$column_name ='Tables_in_'.$mydbname;

// OR (line3+line4
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tbl FROM information_schema.tables" WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = \"'.$mydbname.'\"; ");
$column_name ='tbl';


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $options .= '<option value="' . $row[$column_name] . '">' . $row[$column_name] . '</option>';


echo '<select name="users" onchange="showTables(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="0">Select a table:</option>';
echo  $options;
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify code to this:

```
 <select name="db_tablelist" onchange="showTables(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select a table:</option>';
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">'.$row[0].''; } echo '';
 echo '</select>
 </form>
 <br>
 <div id="tablesDb"><b>All content from selected table will be listed there.</b></div></div>';
```

And now everything works .